# Group by, and sum, and generate an object for each array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I need to group by id and sum, but I need a new object for each result:

```
let data = [
    {"id":"2018", "name":"test", "total":1200},
    {"id":"2019", "name":"wath", "total":1500},
    {"id":"2019", "name":"wath", "total":1800},
    {"id":"2020", "name":"zooi", "total":1000},
]
```

I have this code that returns just one object with the result

```
let result = data.reduce(function (r, o) {
    (r[o.id])?
        r[o.id] += o.total:
        r[o.id] = o.total;
    return r;
});
```

But I need some like this:

```
[
    {"id":"2018", "name":"test", "total":1200},
    {"id":"2019", "name":"wath", "total":2300},
    {"id":"2020", "name":"zooi", "total":1000},
]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
const result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => (r[o.id]
  ? (r[o.id].total += o.total)
  : (r[o.id] = {...o}), r), {}));
```

Comment: what does the '?' and the ':' mean?

Comment: @BreadBoard.ini it's known as the ternary operator. Basically it's an inline if-else condition. You can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 10):

```js
let data =[
    {"id":"2018", "name":"test", "total":1200},
    {"id":"2019", "name":"wath", "total":1500},
    {"id":"2019", "name":"wath", "total":1800},
    {"id":"2020", "name":"zooi", "total":1000},
];

let map = data.reduce((prev, next) =>{
  if (next.id in prev) {
    prev[next.id].total += next.total;
  } else {
     prev[next.id] = next;
  }
  return prev;
}, {});

let result = Object.keys(map).map(id => map[id]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I don't see why you changed the code of the `reduce`. The only thing that mattered was `Object.keys(map).map(id => map[id])`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I did not understand what do you want to say. Is is bad?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz No no. I meant to say that the `reduce` code change was irrelevant. Your answer could've been as short as saying, _Do `result = Object.keys(map).map(id => map[id]);`_, without having to rewrite `reduce` code.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir No,that will not be correct answer. We need to group by `id` and sum `total` values. So reduce is required

Answer (score 1):

Change your `reduce` to:

```
let result = data.reduce(function(acc, obj) {             // for each obj in data
    if(acc.map.hasOwnProperty(obj.id)) {                  // if the map contains an object for the current object's id
        acc.map[obj.id].total += +obj.total;              // then add the current object's total to it
    } else {                                              // otherwise
        var newObj = Object.assign({}, obj);              // create a new object (a copy of the current object)
        acc.map[obj.id] = newObj;                         // add the new object to both the map
        acc.data.push(newObj);                            // ... and the data array
    }
    return acc;
}, {data: [], map: {}}).data;                             // the accumulator should have an array for the data objects (which will be our result) and a map object which maps the ids to the objects in the data array. Once our reduce finishes its work, we assign the data array of the accumulator to result
```

**Example:**

```js
let data =[ {"id":"2018", "name":"test", "total":1200}, {"id":"2019", "name":"wath", "total":1500}, {"id":"2019", "name":"wath", "total":1800}, {"id":"2020", "name":"zooi", "total":1000} ];

let result = data.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
    if(acc.map.hasOwnProperty(obj.id)) {
        acc.map[obj.id].total += +obj.total;
    } else {
        var newObj = Object.assign({}, obj);
        acc.map[obj.id] = newObj;
        acc.data.push(newObj);
    }
    return acc;
}, {data: [], map: {}}).data;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This really helped me thanks :) Very simple and detailed example

Answer (score -1):

```
import uniqBy from 'lodash/uniqBy'

export function transform (array) {
  const newArray = []
  const uniq = uniqBy(array, 'id')

  uniq.forEach(item => {
    const total = array
      .filter(({id}) => item.id === id)
      .reduce((sum, current) => sum + current.total, 0)

    newArray.push({
      ...item,
      total
    })
  })

  return newArray
}
```