# JavaScript Infinity loop in foreach statement

Tags: javascript

i wrote this code and he executed in an infinite loop

```
    var listStock=[{"price":200,"libelle":"bus"},{"price":5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":6,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":12,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":95,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":22,"libelle":"food"},{"price":6,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":6,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":15,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":23,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":12,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":10.5,"libelle":"food"},{"price":23,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":13.5,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":20,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":20,"libelle":"arrondissement"},{"price":15,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":9,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":34,"libelle":"food"},{"price":10,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":3.5,"libelle":"food"},{"price":23,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":12,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":33,"libelle":"tran"},{"price":4,"libelle":"pisri"},{"price":15,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":5,"libelle":"pisri"},{"price":20,"libelle":"tobis"},{"price":6,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":45,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":4,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":120,"libelle":"tran"},{"price":3,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":8,"libelle":"pisri"},{"price":60,"libelle":"covoiturage"},{"price":7,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":7,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":2,"libelle":"pisri"},{"price":1,"libelle":"gift"},{"price":29,"libelle":"food"},{"price":23,"libelle":"covoiturage"}];

var listLib=[];
listStock.forEach(function(item, index) {
  var lib=item.libelle;var pr=item.price;
  if(listLib.length==0){
    var objet={};objet.libelle=lib;objet.price=pr;
    listLib.push(objet);
  }else{
    listLib.forEach(function(item1,index1){
      if(item1.libelle==lib){
        item1.price=item1.price+pr;
      }else{
        var objet={};objet.libelle=lib;objet.price=pr;
        listLib.push(objet);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

i want to sum prices by label

Comment: Does this answer your question? [group by, and sum, and generate a object for each array javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338082/group-by-and-sum-and-generate-a-object-for-each-array-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `listLib.push` inside a loop on `listLib`, and you are doing this for *every* iteration where the object does not match. And so you repeatedly add a similar object to `listLib`.

You should just find the matching entry, and potentially add a new object *after* that search, not *during* the search. So if we stick to your code, then the `else` part of your code should be modified to this:

```
    var found = false;
    for (let item1 of listLib) {
      if(item1.libelle==lib){
        item1.price=item1.price+pr;
        found = true;
        break; // No need to look further
      }
    }
    // And then AFTER the loop, check if we need to add the object:
    if (!found) {
        var objet={};objet.libelle=lib;objet.price=pr;
        listLib.push(objet);
    }
```

Even better is to key your input data first, using a Map. Because then the look-up is easy and has better performance:

```js
var listStock=[{"price":200,"libelle":"bus"},{"price":5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":6,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":12,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":95,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":22,"libelle":"food"},{"price":6,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":6,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":15,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":23,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":12,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":10.5,"libelle":"food"},{"price":23,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":13.5,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":20,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":20,"libelle":"arrondissement"},{"price":15,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":9,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":34,"libelle":"food"},{"price":10,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":3.5,"libelle":"food"},{"price":23,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":12,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":33,"libelle":"tran"},{"price":4,"libelle":"pisri"},{"price":15,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":5,"libelle":"pisri"},{"price":20,"libelle":"tobis"},{"price":6,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":45,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":4,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":120,"libelle":"tran"},{"price":3,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":8,"libelle":"pisri"},{"price":60,"libelle":"covoiturage"},{"price":7,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":7,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":2,"libelle":"pisri"},{"price":1,"libelle":"gift"},{"price":29,"libelle":"food"},{"price":23,"libelle":"covoiturage"}];

let map = new Map(listStock.map(({libelle}) => [libelle, {libelle, price: 0}]));
for (let {price, libelle} of listStock) map.get(libelle).price += price;
let result = Array.from(map.values());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var listStock=JSON.parse(`[{"price":200,"libelle":"bus"},{"price":5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":6,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":12,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":95,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":22,"libelle":"food"},{"price":6,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":6,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":15,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":23,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":12,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":10.5,"libelle":"food"},{"price":23,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":13.5,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":20,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":20,"libelle":"arrondissement"},{"price":15,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":9,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":34,"libelle":"food"},{"price":10,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":3.5,"libelle":"food"},{"price":23,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":12,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":33,"libelle":"tran"},{"price":4,"libelle":"pisri"},{"price":15,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":5,"libelle":"pisri"},{"price":20,"libelle":"tobis"},{"price":6,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":45,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":4,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":7.5,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":120,"libelle":"tran"},{"price":3,"libelle":"librairie"},{"price":8,"libelle":"pisri"},{"price":60,"libelle":"covoiturage"},{"price":7,"libelle":"grand taxi"},{"price":7,"libelle":"tram"},{"price":2,"libelle":"pisri"},{"price":1,"libelle":"gift"},{"price":29,"libelle":"food"},{"price":23,"libelle":"covoiturage"}]`);

//console.log(listStock)
const finalData=listStock.reduce((acc,curr)=>{

const label=curr.libelle;
  acc[label]=acc[label]? acc[label]+ curr.price : curr.price || 0;

  return acc;
},{})

console.log(finalData)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```