# Cash Register in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I need my code to return the following:

```
{
  status: 'OPEN',
  change: [
    ['TWENTY', 60],
    ['TEN', 20],
    ['FIVE', 15],
    ['ONE', 1],
    ['QUARTER', 0.5],
    ['DIME', 0.2],
    ['PENNY', 0.04],
  ],
};
```

but right now it returns:

```
{
  status: 'OPEN',
  change: [
    ['TWENTY', 20],
    ['TWENTY', 20],
    ['TWENTY', 20],
    ['TEN', 10],
    ['TEN', 10],
    ['FIVE', 5],
    ['FIVE', 5],
    ['FIVE', 5],
    ['ONE', 1],
    ['QUARTER', 0.25],
    ['QUARTER', 0.25],
    ['DIME', 0.1],
    ['DIME', 0.1],
    ['PENNY', 0.01],
    ['PENNY', 0.01],
    ['PENNY', 0.01],
    ['PENNY', 0.01],
  ],
};
```

How can I sum all arrays whose first element is the same? I´ve tried using a loop, but it didn't work the way I wanted

````
  let cashInDrawer = cid;
  let cashInDrawerReverse = cashInDrawer.reverse();
  let currencyUnits = [
     ["ONE HUNDRED", 100],
     ["TWENTY", 20],
     ["TEN", 10],
     ["FIVE", 5],
     ["ONE", 1],
     ["QUARTER", 0.25],
     ["DIME", 0.1],
     ["NICKEL", 0.05],
     ["PENNY", 0.01]
  ];

  let availableMoney = [];
  let totalAvailableMoney = 0;
  let totalChange = cash - price;
  let change = []
  
  //Check the available money:
  for(let index = 0; index < cid.length; index++){
    availableMoney.push(cid[index][1]);
  }

  availableMoney.reverse();

  //Total of available money:
  
  for(let f = 0; f < availableMoney.length; f++){
    totalAvailableMoney += availableMoney[f];
  }

//Returns:

  if(totalChange > totalAvailableMoney){
    return {status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS", change: []}
  }
  else if (totalChange === totalAvailableMoney){
    return {status: "CLOSED", change: cashInDrawer.reverse()}
  } 
  else {
    for(var i = 0; i < cashInDrawerReverse.length; i++){
     if(cashInDrawerReverse[i][1] != 0){
      while(totalChange >= currencyUnits[i][1] && cashInDrawerReverse[i][1] > 0){ 
          change.push(currencyUnits[i]);
          cashInDrawerReverse[i][1] -= currencyUnits[i][1];
          totalChange -=  currencyUnits[i][1];
          totalChange = totalChange.toFixed(2); 
      } 
     }
    }
    if(totalChange == 0){
    return {status: "OPEN", change: change}
    } else {
      return {status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS", change: []}
    }
  }

}


console.log(checkCashRegister(3.26, 100, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.1], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90], ["FIVE", 55], ["TEN", 20], ["TWENTY", 60], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]]))```
````

Comment: Looks like you just need to [group and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68339586/grouping-an-array-and-then-summing-values) by coin type, though it would be simple enough to avoid having to do it afterwords by simply making it an object keyed by coin instead of an array of tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const change = [['TWENTY', 20],
  ['TWENTY', 20], ['TWENTY', 20], ['TEN', 10], ['TEN', 10], ['FIVE', 5], ['FIVE', 5], ['FIVE', 5], ['ONE', 1], ['QUARTER', 0.25], ['QUARTER', 0.25], ['DIME', 0.1], ['DIME', 0.1], ['PENNY', 0.01], ['PENNY', 0.01], ['PENNY', 0.01], ['PENNY', 0.01]]
  

const result = {}
for (const [denomination, amount] of change) {
  if (!result[denomination]) {
    result[denomination] = amount
  } else {
    result[denomination] += amount
  }
}

console.log(Object.keys(result).map(key => ([key, result[key]])))
```